# ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I am working on python3 jupyter notebook. I am creating a predictive model and I'm the following code at a particular step:

```
logit1 = sm.Logit(a, b).fit()
```

Here, a and b have exactly shame shape and type:

- a -  shape : (842713,) ; type : pandas.core.series.Series
- b -  shape : (842713,) ; type : pandas.core.series.Series

I am getting the following error at this step:

**ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned.**

I have already tried lookig for similar questions but cannot find anything with an answer that works.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example where you defined a and b, so people can reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi, I tried recreating the error on a sample data but it was running fine without any error. While doing so, I rechecked my data as well. The root cause of the error was that one of the dataframe has a lot of NaN values. This is again weird because the data from which I am copying the values into dataframe b has no NaN values, but while copying, somehow fills b with a lot a NaN values.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
In my case, both Series are the same length and the indices are visually equal but they didn't share the same location.
So I made sure that both Series or DataFrames have exactly the same indices.
I tried this and it solved the problem:

```
a.reindex(b.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to list type and then pass as argument to Logit() i.e 
logit1 = sm.Logit(list(a), list(b)).fit()

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even converting to list will result in error *cannot perform reduce with flexible type*. So it's better to convert it into numpy arrays.
e.g.:

```
X_train, y_train -> np.array(y_train), np.array(X_train)
```